# Fresh Install Cpanel Button on form not Post

Tags: button, post, methods, cpanel

I trying to search on google but no result... 
my php project run on many cpanel without errors / Warnings but yesterday on fresh install cpanel i got this problem and can't solve it ..

```
 <form role="form" method="post">
      <div class="col-lg-3" style="margin-bottom: 10px;">
               <button name="cash"  valeu="0"
              class="btn btn-info btn-sm btn-block">Button</button>
         <input type="hidden" value="7" id="days" name="days">
      </div>
    </form>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['cash']))
{
echo 'Button Working';
}
?>
```

Comment: What exactly did you try?

Comment: what you mean what exactly i try? im trying to post and not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution build again easyapache with php 5.5 on php 5.6 not working dunno why...